# HTML text-align property works on HTML objects that aren't text?

Tags: html, css

I'm an entry-level web developer and I'm trying to make sure I understand the HTML "logic" (if there is any) behind everything I do, rather than just moving forth once I've jerry-rigged my page into how I intended it to look.

For instance, I wanted a `textarea` object to be horizontally centered inside a particular `div`, so I gave that `div` the property `text-align: center;`, which I know from experience will accomplish my intended task. But I'd like to make sure I fully understand why this works.

Any answers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`text-align` is a bit of a misnomer.

As the [W3 states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#alignment-prop):

> This property describes how inline-level content of a block container
>   is aligned

And [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align):

> The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is
>   aligned in its parent block element. text-align does not control the
>   alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content.

So as you can see, it refers to inline content, not just text. I guess `inline-content-align` wasn't as catchy.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement j08691's answer, if you want to use `text-align: center` for horizontal centering, you will have to declare your element, say, `<textarea>` as an inline or inline-block element.

If you are working with a block-level element though, you can use `margin: 0 auto;` to achieve the same effect &mdash, in fact, just setting left and right margins to `auto` will also do the trick.